# Cruisecontrol actions after a successful build?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

I am using cruisecontrol (phpCruiseControl to be precise) as a CI server and have my build script running on an automated basis. Is there anyway to add tasks to the cruisecontrol config script to be actions upon a successful build?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only have experience with the Java based CruiseControl so I don't really know if phpCruiseControl is any different but for the "common" CruiseControl you can define in the configuration file (usually config.xml) you have the option of adding "publishers".
These run after the build completed.
In reply to your question, you need to add to the configuration an <onsuccess> element under the publishers section in it you can call whatever publisher you like.
read the [documentation](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#onsuccess) for the explanation.
Basically you want something like this:

```
<cruisecontrol>
   <project>
     <publishers>
       <onsuccess>
         <antpublisher buildfile="myTasks.xml">
         ...
```

Comment: Nice one thanks. From my understanding so far phpUnderControl works very similar to the Java version and I think the build config is identical, hence my ambiguous question, thanks again!